# reveal.js how to start in middle of presentation

Tags: reveal.js

Is it possible to start in the middle of a presentation with reveal.js? I would like the first slide to have the option of going up,down,foward ,back to act like a quiz. or do any of you know of a program that can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer, but hope that this answer could help somebody in the future.

You can use the reveal.js API to achieve that.

Simply use the call to Reveal.slide function after the 'ready' event is called.

```
Reveal.slide( indexh, indexv, indexf );
```

```js
Reveal.initialize();
Reveal.addEventListener( 'ready', function( event ) {
  Reveal.slide(2, 1); //go to slide horizontal / vertical
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/3.0.0/css/reveal.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/3.0.0/css/theme/simple.css" id="theme">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/3.0.0/css/theme/moon.css">
    
<div class="reveal">
   <div class="slides">
    <section>Slide 1</section>
    <section>Slide 2</section>
        <section>
          <section>Slide 3</section>
          <section>Slide 3.1</section>
          <section>Slide 3.2</section>
          <section>Slide 3.3</section>
        </section>
        <section>Slide 4</section>
        <section>
          <section>Slide 5</section>
          <section>Slide 5.1</section>
          <section>Slide 5.2</section>
          
        </section>
          
        <section>Slide 6</section>
   </div>
</div>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headjs/1.0.3/head.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/3.0.0"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try giving links between the slides as below
    <section id="idname">
     Your content
   </section>
```

Then just in some other slide where you want to link to this slide as below

```
<a href="#/idname"> Your text </a>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that not an answer of OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to just give out a link to the middle slide you want to start on:

http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/2/2

A more complex solution would be to add `id="home"` to the first slide. Then use the following javascript to listen for state changes to that slide:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'home', function() {
  // If user is on first slide, force change to desired slide
  Reveal.slide( 2, 2);
}, false );
```

You might potentially be able to use this API call as well:

```
Reveal.isFirstSlide();
```